# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

There are a million similar questions, but i tried everything and i can't find the solution. I have this tables :
(Using MySQL)

```
create table users (
  user_id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  
  username varchar(256) not null,
  password varchar(256) not null,
  enabled boolean
);
create unique index ix_users_name on users (username);

create table groups (
    group_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  
    group_name varchar(50) not null 
);
create unique index ix_groups_name on groups (group_name);
```

And i want to create this one.

```
create table group_members (
    group_member_id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    user_id bigint not null,
    group_id int not null,
    constraint fk_group_members_1 foreign key(user_id) references users(user_id),
    constraint fk_group_members_2 foreign key(group_id) references groups(group_id)
);
create unique index ix_member_group on group_members (user_id,group_id);
```

Then it throws

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Do you know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field definitions on BOTH sides of the FK must match:

```
t1: user_id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  
                   ^^^^^^^^ 
t2: user_id bigint not null,
```

The `t1` definition is `unsigned`, which means it's theoretically possible to create a record in t1 which cannot be represented in t2, as T1's range of possible IDs is 0->2^64, v.s. the -2^63-> + 2^63 in t2.